# Using GAE channels without browser

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I want to write GAE based application that synchronizes information between computers/phones. Right now I am only querying periodically, which causes delays or requires user to click a button to refresh manually.

With GAE channels, it should be possible to do it this way that a device can be notified when it should refresh. However, since I want it to be a desktop app (not web app), I am wondering if I can write my own client to channel API? Or grab whatever's out there.

Is the protocol documented or are there clients available for anything other than JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only official interface is the Javascript client library. Although you could reverse-engineer how it works, since it's not a documented part of the interface, it could change at any time without notice.

If you're interfacing with Android phones or iPhones, each of them has a 'push' messaging API that you could use (Cloud to Device Messaging for Android, and Push Messaging for iPhone).

Comment: While I also wanted the same thing for PC, I guess it's still better than nothing.

Comment: For a desktop PC app you could still embed a hidden browser component and keep the Channel open in that for communication. It would probably be more reliable in the long run.

Comment: Someone has already started a [python client implementation](http://schibum.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-google-appengine-channel-api-with.html), if that's your language of preference.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a Java implementation for the Channels API.  It was just released days ago and is available via git at https://github.com/gvsumasl/jacc.  I've also taken the liberty of forking it and providing a mavenized version at https://github.com/hatboyzero/jacc.